# Change text and background of CComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to color edit box of CComboBox. But I want to do that for CBS_DROPDOWN style and CBS_DROPDOWNLIST either.
I override

```
HBRUSH CMyComboBox::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
HBRUSH hbr = CComboBox::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

// TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

if(CTLCOLOR_EDIT == nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetTextColor(m_crAlertText);
    pDC->SetBkColor(m_crAlertBkg);
    hbr = m_hBrushAlert;
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
}

// TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired

return hbr;
}
```

but this is *not working* if CComboBox has CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style ... why ?

Later edit:

Yes, I already try that:

```
HBRUSH CMyComboBox::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
HBRUSH hbr = CComboBox::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

// TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

    //  if(CTLCOLOR_STATIC == nCtlColor)
    if(CTLCOLOR_EDIT == nCtlColor || CTLCOLOR_STATIC == nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetTextColor(m_crAlertText);
    pDC->SetBkColor(m_crAlertBkg);
    hbr = m_hBrushAlert;
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
}

// TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired

return hbr;
}
```

seem not working ... I am not figure out why ...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775796(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **CBS_DROPDOWNLIST** Similar to CBS_DROPDOWN, except that the edit control is replaced by a static text item that displays the current
>   selection in the list box.

So, the reason you can't change the colour of the edit control is that there *is no* edit control when you use this style. Therefore the condition `if(CTLCOLOR_EDIT == nCtlColor)` will never be true. You might wish to try testing for `CTLCOLOR_STATIC`.